# MenuItem with popup textbox

Tags: wpf, menuitem

I have WPF ContextMenu with MenuItems that support custom style. 
MenuItem is a ToggleButton. When the ToggleButton is checked the popup with textbox and close button appears.

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuItem" >
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="Border" Height="25"
                        Background="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}">
                            <ToggleButton Name="tbtnOpenPopup">
                                <ToggleButton.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                                    <Border Name="externalBorder" Background="Transparent"
                                                        BorderThickness="0">
                                                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    </Border>
                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                            <Setter TargetName="externalBorder" Property = "Background" Value="{StaticResource DropDownHighlightedBackgroundColor}"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </ToggleButton.Style>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="7"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                      Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                    <Path Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1"
                                          Data="M0,3 L5,0 L0,-3 L0,3 Z"
                                          Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ToggleButton>
                        </Border>
                        <Popup Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Name="Popup"
                            Placement="Right"
                            AllowsTransparency="True" 
                            Focusable="False"
                            StaysOpen="True"
                            IsOpen="False"
                            PopupAnimation="None">
                            <Grid Name="DropDown"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                            MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="22"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border MinHeight="25" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                    Background="{StaticResource DropDownBackgroundColor}"
                                    BorderThickness="0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Some text" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <Button Name="closeButton" 
                                    Content="X"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger SourceName="tbtnOpenPopup" Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Popup" Property="IsOpen" Value="true"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M5,3 L0,0 L5,-3 L5,3 Z"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="closeButton" Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="tbtnOpenPopup" Property="IsChecked" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I want the popup textbox to close when the "closeButton" pressed, and the ContextMenu to stays open. But when the "closeButton" pressed the ContextMenu closed.

I couldn't understand why it's happining.

Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, a context menu will close when focus is set elsewhere.  Clicking your ToggleButton is within the ContextMenu, so that's okay - but when you click on the close button, you're clicking outside the ContextMenu and it closes.

(Remember that a ContextMenu is a popup, and not part of the visual tree of the owner control.)

Answer (score 0):

This type of requirement calls for implementing a custom popup based context menu as context menus will close (even is `StaysOpen` is true), after something else outside the context menu gets focus (in your case the popup based close button).

:(